# Is the diffusion coefficient time-dependent?

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-equations, diffusion

It is known that in the partial differential equation:

## $$u_t=au_{xx} $$

within the limits $0<x<1$ and $a>0$, the diffusion coefficient, arises in the mathematical modelling of a process of heat conduction in a rod.

If $k$ is *heat conductivity*, $\rho$ *density of material* and $c_p$ is *heat capacity*, then $a=\frac{k}{\rho c_p}$.

I wonder if diffusion coefficient is time-dependent i.e, $a=a(t)>0$: is there any physical situation in which the following boundary condition occurs: $u_x(0,t)+hu(0,t)=0$, where $h>0$ constant. This boundary condition corresponds to a Newton-cooling type of heat loss on the boundary with ambient temperature scaled to zero.

Question: Is it possible that $h$ is a constant in the case of time-dependent diffusion coefficient?